# Using Bash to tidy an Apache configuration script

Tags: shell-script

Let's imagine we have a poorly indented but working configuration file (virtual host) like `www-example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
 DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory /var/www/example.com/public>
AllowOverride All
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>




    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-com-access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The desired output would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-com-access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

We wish to "`tidy`" this configuration file (i.e.: fix the indentation) from within a bash script (without breaking the configuration file).

Which command-line tool should I use for this task?

I have tried:

- `xml_pp test.txt` (which fails because it's not technically XML due to ''*:80>'' at the top as part of ''>'')
- Using `tidy`

Comment: Edit the question and add the expected output.

Comment: @NasirRiley: Sure. Done. Please see above.